# Should we clean up the [anonymous] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation, clean-up

There are 2 main uses for this tag - Anonymous functions and methods, and anonymous login functionality, however there are also a handful of questions where the subject matter is on about hiding IP addresses over proxy and other things.

There are already [anonymous-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anonymous-function) and [anonymous-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anonymous-method) tags, which would cover the large majority of these, leaving the [anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anonymous) only for authentication (which would beg the question of whether we should create an [anonymous-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anonymous-authentication) tag and remove the anonymous tag entirely)

Should we go through the effort to clean these up?

Comment: Is this a burninate request, or just a discussion? I certainly agree in principle, "anonymous" by itself is rather ambiguous, and therefore not a good tag.

Comment: That's sort of what the discussion was intended to be about. There are areas where it is ambiguous, however there aren't the tags available at the moment to allow those questions to become unambiguous (such as my suggestion of moving questions to [tag:anonymous-function] and creating an [tag:anonymous-authentication] tag). It's a question of whether to rename the tag, and migrate those on function and method topics to the correct tag, and keep the [tag:anonymous] tag around, or whether to burniate the [tag:anonymous] tag in its entirety after the migration

Comment: Although, reading over the tag description, the tag was intended for anonymous functions and methods, but is currently being misused for authentication and other ways to stay anonymous, so there is certainly a case for burnification

Comment: Add [anonymous-authentication], clean up all the [anonymous] questions, and burn the latter tag.  If it's kept around it'll continue to be (ab)used over and over again until we repeat the discussion in a few years.  600 questions isn't a huge number to clean up, so let's just do it now.

Comment: Well if you're going to clean it up you also need [anonymous-type].

Comment: Who's "we"? Or are we not naming them? ;)

Comment: Tags like [anonymous-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anonymous-method) that have 0 questions, no description, etc. get auto-deleted within about a week, right? Definitely seems redundant to [anonymous-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anonymous-function)