# Let's burninate the [anonymous]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

#### Pretext

Here's a link to the small discussion about this:

[Should we clean up the [anonymous] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372123/should-we-clean-up-the-anonymous-tag)

#### The Questions 4:

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No.

[anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anonymous) has a variety of questions, mostly on the topic of anonymous functions and methods (the tags purpose - from it's description), however it also contains questions on the topic of anonymous authentication and hiding IP addresses, amongst others.

Essentially, this tag is ambiguous and open to interpretation.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Yes.

[anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anonymous) refers to anonymous functions and methods - however, there are also the tags [anonymous-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anonymous-function) and [anonymous-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anonymous-method) that can account for these on-topic (for tag) questions.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No. Not without more context (function, authentication, or just staying anonymous?)

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No, as displayed above.

#### The Solution

Create a [anonymous-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anonymous-authentication) tag and migrate questions on the topic of authentication to this tag, and migrate the questions that refer to [anonymous-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anonymous-function)s to the more specific tag. For other questions that don't follow this pattern, it'd be more of a case by case basis.

But finally, Burninate the [anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anonymous) tag.

Comment: We already have [tag:lambda] for anonymous functions.  Why wouldn't anonymous authentication fit underneath the [tag:authentication] umbrella?